# text box with emoji property data-emojiable="true" on keypress not working

Tags: html, keypress

my initial HTML

```
<div class="p-10 p-chat-box">
<div class="input-group">
  <span  class="input-group-addon">
   <img src="assets/images/emojis/1f603.png" class="letter-icon">
  </span>
  <p class="lead emoji-picker-container"><input id="readyforchat" data-emojiable="true" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a message ..."></p>
  </span>' + attachMentList + '<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick=NewsWidget.startchat(event) class="input-group-addon">
  <i class="icon-arrow-right6"></i>
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

i am using emojji.js for generating emoji in text box with data-emojiable="true" property html will look like after applying(emojiable="true") this property on input type="text"

From Favorite
Web Link
Write a Note
Pick a file
Photo from gallery

with the id of "readyforchat". BUT my problem is that the jQuery keypress event not working on this id "readyforchat".please help me how can i achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding your code again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Add this code .
chat_form is claas of your form and chat_box is your chat input field class.

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.comment_reply_form').on('keydown', '.chat_box', function (e)
{
var key = e.which;
switch (key) {
case 13: // enter
//your code here
break;
default:
break;
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

for onkey event please modify your emojiarea.js file and replace 323 line with this  code

```
 this.$editor = $('<div onkeydown="comment(this,event)">').addClass('emoji-wysiwyg-editor').addClass($($textarea)[0].className);
```

Call function

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function comment(a,event){
var key = event.which;
if(key==13){
     event.preventDefault(event);

//your code
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
"onkeypress": "return chatKeyPressed(event)"
```

in `jquery.emojiarea.js` in function `this.$editor.attr` at line 351

```
this.$editor.attr({
    'data-id': id,
    'data-type': 'input',
    'placeholder': $textarea.attr('placeholder'),
    'contenteditable': 'true',
    "onkeypress": "return chatKeyPressed(event)"
});
```

Now you can add JavaScript function in your `HTML` like following

```
function chatKeyPressed(e) {
    //key is pressed
}
```

which will be called when key is pressed in

```
<input id="readyforchat" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it using the parent div:

```
$('#message-zone-inner').on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#message-zone-inner button').click();
        }
    });
```

So basically it will monitor the parent div containing the input field, detect if enter has been pressed and click on the "Send" button automatically (you could also submit the form instead).